# Testing the $? global variable in a ruby rspec

Tags: ruby, tdd, rspec2

I have a piece of code like:

```
output = `shell-command-to-run`
unless $?.success?
  raise "Failure running shell command!"
end
```

I've mocked the backtick method to prevent the external shell command from running during my specs, but I've not found a way to set the `$?` global variable to exercise the failure side of the spec.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should have a script that returns the sorts of errors you're expecting to uncover so you can test a variety of conditions. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

exit(ARGV[0].to_i)
```

You can then pass in the exit code you want to trap.

Instead of mocking the call, you just run a different script entirely to validate it handles errors correctly.